# VLC .bat Script: combination of --directx-device & --input-slave does not work

Tags: video, directx, vlc, master-slave, multiscreen

I would like to set up a Video Installation. I want to play master and slave video in two different screens automatically, so I can load the .bat in to the startup folder.

Using the latest VLC on Win7 64bit.

I'm trying to use the Command line **--input-slave** to play two synced videos together, that works well.

**WORKING CODE:**

`start "first VLC" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\a.mov --input-slave C:\Users\acer\Desktop\b.mov
 --start-time 0 --input-repeat=-1`

The command `--directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY1" & --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY2"` is used to distribute the Clips on each Display .. *that also works but only if I start two separate VLCs.*

**WORKING CODE:**

`start "first VLC" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\a.mov --no-embedded-video
--directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY1" --fullscreen --loop
  start "second VLC" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 
 C:\Users\acer\Desktop\b.mov --no-embedded-video
 --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY2" --fullscreen --loop`

BUT the *combination* of the two does NOT work.

How do I run `--directx-device` and  `--input-slave` in combination?

I tried:

`start "first VLC" "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" 
C:\Users\acer\Desktop\a.mov --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY1"
 --input-slave C:\Users\acer\Desktop\b.mov --directx-device="\\.\DISPLAY2" --fullscreen --start-time 0 --input-repeat=-1`

But it does not properly work. VLC shows both clips either on one or the other screen together. But not each on the designated display.

Please help me to find a fix! I definitely need the videos synced via --input-slave otherwise they will run apart after a while. Maybe you can just give me a hint if it's possible at all or not.

Comment: @SagarPatel: regarding your edit, I think the unordered lists ("bullet points") were not appropriate here. Lists are for related items that need to be enumerated together, and not for ordinary paragraph text. Don't overuse formatting features just because they are available! `:-)`

Comment: After some more testing. I don't think its possible. I hope I'm wrong but the slave seems not to regarded as a self-sufficient video/window/file .. it does not obey to commands. just the master goes. 
But I hope I'm wrong. 

Does anyone know how to do that still ?
Command line / Two different videos (same length but different resolution and ratio) / played in sync / on two screens / one PC / fullscreen / looping

Answer (score 0):

Use --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1 instead of -directx-device="\.\DISPLAY2".

```
vlc.exe "video1.mp4" --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1 --fullscreen --input-slave="video2.mp4"
```